# Given A∧B what is the equivalent using just → and ⊕(Xor)

Tags: logical-operators, or-operator, and-operator

Consider the set of connectives consisting of just → and ⊕, where ⊕ is an exclusive OR connective: A⊕B is true if and only if A and B have the opposite truth values (one is true and the other one false).

Given A∧B what is the equivalent formula using only → and ⊕(Xor).

Comment: What does the arrow mean?

Comment: is the -> arrow logical implication? If the only thing you have is xor,then you can't do it. Xor is invertible and is not

Comment: The -> arrow does mean logical Implication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming that -> is [the material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional).

```
A and B is equivalent to not(A implies not B)

not C is equivalent to (C implies C) xor C
```

so

```
not B is equivalent to (B implies B) xor B)
```

and

```
A implies not B  equivalent to A implies ((B implies B) xor B))
```

finally the equivalent expression is

```
((A implies ((B implies B) xor B)) implies (A implies ((B implies B) xor B)))xor (A implies ((B implies B) xor B))
```

in your notation:

```
((A → ((B → B) ⊕ B)) → (A → ((B → B) ⊕ B)))⊕ (A → ((B → B) ⊕ B))
```

with some care you can surely minimize these formulas

Checking the final formula [on wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((A+implies+((B+implies+B)+xor+B))+implies+(A+implies+((B+implies+B)+xor+B)))xor+(A+implies+((B+implies+B)+xor+B)))

A general framework to answer such questions is [functional completness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).
The people at mathoverflow might be helpful.

EDIT

i've made a mess of copying the long formulas, corrected now

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. If this answers your question you might want to accept the answer

Comment: Would you know to find the equivalent formula of A∨B